# Replace value in result by a specific value

Tags: sql

I need to make a query to collect some data from a database via SQL. In this data there is 1 value used as collection value. This are ID's of courses given. Sometimes a course can be given about f.e. Office. But people can do a course there for word, excel, powerpoint... But this is all given in 1 course by 1 tutor. Still for statistics I need to know if they participated the course for Word, Excel, Powerpoint ...

Is it possible to replace values in the resultset? With this i mean something like this:

if value = courseValue ==> replace value with specific courseValue (I can get the value via a subquery)

I hope this makes my problem clear and i appriciate all the help!

Comment: Please add the SQL you have written so far to your question

Comment: Is it a single value you want to replace, or (possibly) multiple values?

Comment: You must explain clearly what information you have and what you need.
To me it sounds like you store student's general course information (Office) and want to extract detailed information (Office/Word) by magic.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a case statement in your select to return something other than the course id that is on the row. For example:

```
SELECT 
    field1 AS 'Name',
    CASE 
        WHEN field2 = 'Foo' 
            THEN 'Bar' 
        WHEN field2 = 'Lorem'
            THEN 'Ipsum'
        ELSE 'Some Value'
    END
    AS 'Type',
    field3 AS 'Description'
FROM table
```

Comment: Thanks! I used this at the number (need some more work to do for the name so i tested it first. Got it this way: 
SELECT count(*) as aantal_per_maand, case when p.planning_Cursus_ID = 2087 then 123123 else p.planning_Cursus_ID end as ID, cursus_Naam 
as cursusNaam....

will be like:
SELECT count(*) as aantal_per_maand, case when p.planning_Cursus_ID = 2087 then cursus_Naam = "<select subquery for name>" else cursus_Naam end as cursusNaam... (syntax won't be good i think but it's an brainstorm idea:P)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you will need something along the lines of this:

- Create a new table with "courseID" and "replacementID" columns, fill it for the cases where there *is* a replacement
- In your query do an outer join with this table over the courseID fields and also return the "replacementID", which can be null is there is no replacement
- Use either the replacementID if it isn't null or the courseID